# Facebook image quote to have a link back to website

Tags: facebook

I don't know whether this is possible but i would like to post images with quotes that carry a backlink to my wp blog. I have tried the normal code:

```
< a href=”URL of websitepage” >< img  src= ”imageURL” >< / a>
```

but fb just picks up my website and displays it.